# Sunni view about Hazrat Ameer Mukhtar

Tags: shia-sunni

According to shia view Hazrat Ameer Mukhtar piece be upon him got the government and honestly killed all the mean killers of Maula Hussain(A.S) and his companions(Peace be upon them).

What is the view of the rest of the fiqs about Hazrat Ameer Mukhtar (Peace be upon him)?

Comment: Are you referring to Al Mukhtar bin Abi Ubaid?

Comment: @al ummat , yes he was the same how killed the killers of imam husain (a.s)

Comment: @Zia this is Shia view. I want to know sunni view about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al Mukhtar bin Abi Ubaid Athuqafy, a person who claimed many things among which was that he received revelation.  he called to the avenging of Hussain's killing so that he could take advantage and get to power.  he is the liar whom the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) [mentioned](http://sunnah.com/urn/723760):

> فِي ثَقِيفٍ كَذَّابٌ وَمُبِيرٌ
>
> In Thaqif there will be a great liar (Al Mukhtar) and destroyer (Al Hajjaj)